# How can I set a border around each of my select2 select box?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I want to set a red border around each of my select box with jQuery. But it does not work out:

http://jsfiddle.net/jEADR/3795/

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.2/select2.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.2/select2.css">

<select class="select" style="width:300px">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="Am">Amalapuram</option>
        <option value="An">Anakapalli</option>
        <option value="Ak">Akkayapalem</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select>
    <select class="select" style="width:300px">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="Am">Amalapuram</option>
        <option value="An">Anakapalli</option>
        <option value="Ak">Akkayapalem</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select>

<script>
    $(".select").select2();
    $(".select").each(function() {
    $(this).siblings().find(".select2-container").css({"border-color": "red", "border-weight":"5px", "border-style":"solid"});
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, your code doesn't work because the `select2-container` elements *are* the siblings, so calling `find()` on them to get the children returns nothing. Simply remove the `find()` call, and give the selector to `siblings()`. Also note that you can shorten the `border` rule, like this:

```
$(".select").each(function() {
  $(this).siblings(".select2-container").css('border', '5px solid red');
});
```

However, more importantly, you should note that using JS code for this is a little redundant when you can place the rule directly in your CSS code:

```js
$(".select").select2();
```

```css
.select2-container {
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.2/select2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.2/select2.css">

<select class="select" style="width:300px">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="Am">Amalapuram</option>
  <option value="An">Anakapalli</option>
  <option value="Ak">Akkayapalem</option>
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
<select class="select" style="width:300px">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="Am">Amalapuram</option>
  <option value="An">Anakapalli</option>
  <option value="Ak">Akkayapalem</option>
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

Comment: No , I need jQuery, because I have some cases and if classes I need to work with later

Comment: So I must be able to highlight the specific sibling of my select box.

Comment: I updated my answer for you. I'd still at least suggest you put the styling you need in a CSS class and use `addClass()` over putting the styling in the JS code directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
.select2-selection { border: 1px solid gold!important;}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste.
 Please edit your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Sfili_81's critique is always important, but that's _especially_ important when there's already an accepted answer that's been validated by the community. Under what conditions might your approach be preferred? Are you taking advantage of new capabilities? (It doesn't appear so, but obviously you're not relying on script.)